# How to center the caption in the center of the columns?

Tags: highcharts

I'm using highstock and I want to center the captions in 2 columns so that there are ticks on the sides. How can I do this?[image]

```
`LINK`https://jsfiddle.net/axucvtkw/25/
```

All I was able to get is shown in the demo, there I am building a series and trying to customize the type and alignment for XAxis.

Answer (score 0):

You can use basic chart with categories and scrollable plot area. For example:

```
  chart: {
    scrollablePlotArea: {
      minWidth: 1000
    }
  },
  xAxis: {
    categories: [...],
    tickWidth: 1
  }
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/2drbswo9/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.scrollablePlotArea

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/n6c5qgoj/12/
I need exactly the stock module to solve my problems, with my series being very long and having to count signatures in callback

Comment: Hi @Иван Кондратьев, Unfortunately, Highstock supports only `datetime` x-axis type and the `tickmarkPlacement` option is not available: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.tickmarkPlacement What exactly are the problems that Highstock solves for you?

Comment: 1 Large amount of data in the series
2 Working with a date object
3 The ability to scroll for a date, this is important because I use my own selector.
These are the main ones.

Comment: Only a large amount of data could be tricky to handle without Highstock (due to its data-grouping feature), but the rest can be achieved in Highcharts, for example: https://jsfiddle.net/kxonfp1y/ However, you can report your idea as a feature request here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues

Comment: I hear you, thank you!
There is a related issue where the small width chart skips the X-axis captions in increments of 2 or more, can I affect this? I want to always have all captions.

Comment: You need to set `xAxis.labels.step` to 1. Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/9qfonj26/ API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.labels.step

Comment: But it doesn't work on my demo example
 https://jsfiddle.net/axucvtkw/25/

Comment: In Highstock, you need to disable `ordinal` xAxis and set `tickInterval` to one day. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/8gL70pk9/

Comment: But what if I have a 'month' quantum, what will be the tickInterval? The number of days is different.

Comment: Then the `tickInterval` should be `1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30`. Highcharts will be able to deal with it and show proper dates. Live example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/puhe91xs/